# can't figure why insert sqlite sql statement is not being executed , Xcode

Tags: xcode, sqlite

everything looks good for me, but the prepare_v2 doesn't get SQLITE_OK

the sql instruction is pretty basic, if I copy and paste it on the sqlite manager, it inserts fine

is there anything I am missing?

```
//from view controller

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

DBConnection* dbCon = [DBConnection alloc];
[dbCon init];
[dbCon InsertDataRollNo:@"888"];
```

}

```
-(id)init
{
//[super init];

DBName = @"FoodDB2.sqlite";

NSArray* documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString* documentsDir = [documentsPath objectAtIndex:0];
DBPath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:DBName];

return self;
```

}

```
-(void)InsertDataRollNo:(NSString*)theName
{
[self CheckAndCreateDB];

sqlite3* database;

if(sqlite3_open([DBPath UTF8String], &database)== SQLITE_OK)
{
    NSString* statement;
    sqlite3_stmt* compliedStatement;

    //statement = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"insert into Category(TheName)values('%d')",@"epa"];
    statement = @"insert into Category(TheName)values('aaa')";
    const char* sqlStatement = [statement UTF8String];

    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compliedStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        if(SQLITE_DONE!=sqlite3_step(compliedStatement))
        {
            NSAssert1(0,@"Error by inserting '%s' ", sqlite3_errmsg(database));

        }
        else
        {
            NSAssert1(0,@"cool '%s' ", @"ope");
        }
    }           
    sqlite3_finalize(compliedStatement);
}
sqlite3_close(database);
```

}

```
-(void)CheckAndCreateDB

{



  BOOL success;

NSFileManager* fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:DBPath];

if(success) return;

NSString* databasePathFromApp = [[[NSBundle mainBundle]resourcePath]stringByAppendingPathComponent:DBName];

[fileManager copyItemAtPath:databasePathFromApp toPath:DBPath error:nil];

//[fileManager release];
```

}

Comment: Make sure the path is correct and you have writing permission to the file. Still not working?

Comment: the path is correct, what do you mean permission on the file? mac file system write permission?   I added file system write permission to the sqlite file to everyone and still fails

Comment: Could you post your `-CheckAndCreateDB`?

Comment: I just did it, also I post the init method to start db and my view controller calling it

Comment: You say it's not returning `SQLITE_OK`. So what does it return?

Comment: Im pretty sure is something f**k up with Firefox sqlite manager... but don't know what

Comment: I'm new with Xcode, I'm having a hard time debugging it, trying to add it in some sore of watch list, will tell you soon..

Comment: Just do something like `NSLog(@"Code = %d\n", res)`.

Comment: it returned Code = 1, I'm checking other guys cases, maybe sqlite3_open can't find the sqlite file for some reason and creates a blank one(very stupid) now Im trying to use sqlite3_open_v2 but it is returning 0, it can't find sqlite file... very frustrating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out, actually I was not copying the sqlite file to iPhone project, running good now