# Update value in sqlite iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, sqlite, sdk

I have a simple program that update a record of a table

The table is "person" with two columns "name" and "age";
some records have been inserted, as follows:

```
name age
tom 20
andy 30
han 25
```

Now I am writing a program to update a row in the table:

```
    NSString *database=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"mytable" ofType:@"sqlite"];
    sqlite3_open([database UTF8String],&contactDB);
    NSString *text=@"andy";
    NSString *query=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE person SET age=%d WHERE name='%@'",30,text];
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB,[query UTF8String],-1,&statement,NULL);
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    sqlite3_close(contactDB);
```

The program works fine, but the database is not updated (I am using SQLite Manager to browser the database)

When I try reading from database, it works well:

```
NSString *database=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"mytable" ofType:@"sqlite"];
    sqlite3_open([database UTF8String],&contactDB);
    NSString *query1=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM person WHERE age=%d;",30];
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB,[query1 UTF8String],-1,&statement,NULL);
    sqlite3_step(statement);    
    NSString *result=[[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
    label.text=result;
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    sqlite3_close(contactDB);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 -(void)updateSetting:(NSArray *)arr
  {    
 if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String],&myDatabase)==SQLITE_OK)
  {
 sqlite3_stmt *compiledStmt;

  NSString *sqlStmt=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE setting SET    flow='%@',formate='%@'  WHERE primaryKey=%i;",[arr objectAtIndex:0],[arr objectAtIndex:1],1];
  if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(myDatabase, [sqlStmt UTF8String],-1,&compiledStmt, NULL)==SQLITE_OK)    
  {
  NSLog(@"Successful update");
  }
sqlite3_step(compiledStmt);
sqlite3_close(myDatabase);  
  }

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I already faced this issues.  Whats the problem behind this is you passed the query as a string format so you have to use the `;` at the end of the query statement.

```
NSString *query=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE questionbank SET age=%d WHERE name='%@';",30,text];
```

Comment: hello, I believe ; does not matter, because query SELECT * FROM ... works perfectly for me for both cases with and without ;

Answer (score 1):

Please make a checking like below before you perform your `sqlite3_step` method.

```
const char      *sqlQuery           = "UPDATE SETTINGS SET someFlag = 0";
sqlite3_stmt    *insertStatement    = nil;
int              success            = 0;
if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(sqliteDatabase, sqlQuery, -1, &insertStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    success = sqlite3_step(insertStatement);

    if(insertStatement)
    {
        sqlite3_finalize(insertStatement);
    }

    if(success == SQLITE_ERROR)
    {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
return NO;
```

So that you can figure out, where the problem is.

Comment: I finally got the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11170851/i-can-not-insert-data-into-sqlite3-file-on-xcode

Comment: the sqlite3_step is not necessary when updating the table.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check whether you could access and open the database or not. Simply place your update segment in a if-statement like this: `if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)`.

Also try to add `NSLog(@"%s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));` after your prepare to see if there was any errors.

Comment: it connects to database well. I have try reading from database, it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

The answer for this problem is that the database in the main bundle is read-only

[I can not insert data into sqlite3 file on XCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11170851/i-can-not-insert-data-into-sqlite3-file-on-xcode)